# Reading Input from another programs Console. Java

Tags: java

So here is what I want to do. Im currently managing a TF2(Source Engine Game) server, and 2 console are running at the same time for the server, one for the game and the other to compile stats, both of them have plenty verbose on their console, so I think "Why not create a program that filters both console text, and only leaves the important things", and maybe adding a way to send commands also to both consoles.

Answer (score 0):

Just have the the consoles redirect their output to a file:

Windows: http://blog.crankybit.com/redirecting-output-to-a-file-in-windows-batch-scripts/

*nix: http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/349/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-as-well-as-display-it-out/

Now your Java program can read the files and parse the output. You can even use [Tailer](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html) from Apache Commons to do something whenever the file is updated.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the [`ProcessBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to start the process from within your other java program. You can then attach to the process' output stream via [`Process.getInputStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream%28%29).

Comment: I think that this maybe is what I looking for, i will try to investigate more deeply on how to use this and if it works for me, because I dont want to create a "log file" that will take to much space on disk considering the amount of verbose of both consoles

Answer (score 0):

Named pipes will probably be your best bet here.  They function like a command line pipe.  The difference is that there is a filename that can let you connect two separate commands on difference consoles.  For instance on a *nix/MacOSX system you can do a named pipe like this:

```
$ mkfifo my_pipe
$ echo "information" > my_pipe
```

On a separate console

```
$ cat my_pipe
```

This is equivalent to:

```
$ echo "information" | cat
```

except that you can do it with separate consoles.

You can have your consoles send information to a named pipe and then run your Java code with the pipe as input.  Like this.

```
$ console > my_pipe
```

On another terminal:

```
$ java my_java_code < my_pipe
```

This can also be done on Windows but I'm not sure about the specific syntax of the commands.  This link may help:

[Named Pipes in Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)